# how to find all of the options for a node package?

Tags: node.js, npm

this is a general question about node modules. Everytime I download a node module, I am scrambling online for hints as to what options I can pass into the node module. On github there only seems to be a few options as an example, but what if I want to see what other options are available and what they do? how do I do this? is there a way in the command prompt to see if all of the options exist? 
fore example... how would I see the options for this...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin

Comment: What do you mean by options? If you want documentation, it is usually available either on the projects official website, or in the `README` of the github page. -- In your case the options object is an array of the plugins to use

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for every Node module (package) is available on npm, e.g.:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin

By default what is displayed is the README.md file in the project. Sometimes it contains the entire documentation, sometimes it has links to other documents or websites.

But sometimes it can be empty or outdated because the modules and their documentation is usually created by people on their free time with no obligation to keep it maintained or well documented.

If there is no documentation available or you think that the documentation is insufficient then you can either post an issue (usually on GitHub) or update the documentation and post a pull request.

See the documentation of a given module to know how to contribute or how to post issues. There should be links to issues and pull requests on the right of the module's page on npm.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the William with respect to the usabiity of node modules. While most of the modules have 'some' documentation in the npmjs.com, and 'some' in the module's repository (if public, mostly github), there is no standard form in which the capabilities are represented. Also, in many cases, the documentation is not comprehensive.

Ideally I would expect to have a standard template in the npmjs.com with these below details. This would help accelerate the consumption and serviceability of the module when deployed in large and complex software systems.

1. A high level description of the module.
2. List of its most common use cases.
3. List of its most common (and desired) topologies
4. List of exposed APIs, with their input and expected output, side effects, assumptions.
5. Tips on debugging the potential issues.
6. Potential side effects (cache, memory, open fd's, leftover disc files, network access)

People can add / refine items which they think will improve the usabillity of modules, before we take it up with the npm community.